# Can I autowire all available channels in Sprinng Cloud?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring Cloud app where I have defined channels like this:

```
interface MyEventAChannel {
    @Output("my-event-a")
    fun output(): MessageChannel
}

interface MyEventBChannel {
    @Output("my-event-b")
    fun output(): MessageChannel
}
```

Is it possible to autowire a list of all such channels?

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
// Instead of this:
@Service
class MyService(
    private val channelA: MyEventAChannel,
    private val channelB: MyEventBChannel,
) {


// I want this:
@Service
class MyService(
    private val channels: List<???>
) {
```

Any idea? It's fine for me to write another interface or wrapper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; here's an example (Java)

```java
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(List<MessageChannel> channels) {
    return args -> {
        channels.stream()
            .filter(ch -> ch instanceof DirectWithAttributesChannel)
            .map(ch -> (DirectWithAttributesChannel) ch)
            .forEach(ch -> System.out.println(ch.getAttribute("type") + ": " + ch.getComponentName()));
    };
}
```

Type is `input` or `output`.